# Code to get featureclass name from existing topology

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net

I am creating and validating topology through vb.net and arcobject code.Things are running fine as I am able to add rule and validate it.

Problem is when once the program is run and topology is created. Second time when I am running my code, I have written that if topology exist then delete it and create new topology but I observed that deleting topology every time will corrupt memory.

So Second approach I used is to first delete rule in the existing topology and then featureclass from it and not the topology.

Then new rule and featureclasses are added to same existing topology.
But the problem is I am not able to get the featureclass name in the existing topology. How can I get the name of feature class participated in topology?

The code is as follows-:

```vb
If pdataset.type=esridatasettype.featureclass then
    Dim fcnme as string
    Dim fcarray as Arraylist=New Arraylist
    fcnme=pdataset.name
    fcarray.add(fcnme)
    for i as integer=0 to fcarray.count-1
        pname=fcarray.item(i).tostring
        Dim gp as Geoprocessor=New geoprocessor
        Dim removefc as DataManagementTool.RemoveFeatureclassFromtopology=New DataManagementTool.RemoveFeatureclassFromtopology
        removefc.in_topology=topologyname
        removefc.in_featureclassnme=pname
        Dim sv as object=nothing
        try
           GP.execute(removefc,nothing)
        Catch ex as exception
        end try
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [ITopologyProperties.Classes](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Classes_Property/0025000009t0000000/) property.

1. Use this [sample code](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esrigeodatabase/ITopology_Example.htm) to get a reference to your topology.
2. From your ITopology, get [ITopologyProperties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ITopologyProperties_Interface/0025000009sz000000/).
3. Store ITopologyProperties.Classes in an IEnumFeatureClass.
4. Use the [sample code](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IFeatureClassContainer.htm) here to enumerate over your IEnumFeatureClass to get the feature class you want (since multiple feature classes may be in a single topology, you can get the name, type, etc. of each)